# How can I get a list of posts for a category with WP-API?

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

Should be easy, but didnt find it in the [WP-API docs](http://wp-api.org/guides/working-with-posts.html).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found it, somewhat [hidden][1]

Using the category name:
`/posts?categories=1`

Try this one.

Comment: Hmm, actually it's not *that* hidden in the docs: http://wp-api.org/#posts_retrieve-posts_input

Comment: The link in your comment appears to not be correct anymore (perhaps it was changed on a version upgrade?). Anyways, is it possible to do a negative filter, such as all posts that don't have a `category_name` that is `MyCategory`?

Comment: Changed in v2 `&categories=1`

Comment: It looks like wordpress removed filters from API since Wordpress 4.7. @TomWoodward's answer works.

Answer (score 15):

This question is a duplicate from [this other question here from the forum](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251527/wp-rest-api-filter-by-category-1-and-category-2)

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=20,30
```

The above will return posts from `category 20 OR category 30`

I've tested with custom post types and it also works perfectly

The response and credits go to "Manish Jung Thapa"

Comment: how to make the relation AND?

Answer (score 6):

For category name, two filters should be added like this:

```
add_filter( "rest_post_query", function( $args, $request){
                if ( isset( $request['category_name']) && !empty($request['category_name'] ) ) {
                    $args['category_name'] = $request['category_name'];
                }
                return $args;
            }, 10, 2);


add_filter( "rest_post_collection_params", function($query_params, $post_type){
                $query_params[ 'category_name' ] = array(           
                    'description' => __( 'Category name.' ),
                    'type'        => 'string',
                    'readonly'    => true,
                );
                return $query_params;
            }, 10, 2);
```

Comment: This still works, I believe i seen this on the github issue as well nevertheless ty.

Comment: Thanks! For the record, I noticed for this to work, the category_name query parameter must be BEFORE the _fields parameter.

Answer (score 4):

This code is working for me

> Add to your function.php

```
function rest_filter_by_custom_taxonomy( $args, $request ) {

if ( isset($request['category_slug']) )
{
    $category_slug = sanitize_text_field($request['category_slug']);
    $args['tax_query'] = [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $category_slug,
        ]
    ];
}

return $args;

 }
 add_filter('rest_post_query', 'rest_filter_by_custom_taxonomy', 10, 3);
```

> EX:  /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?category_slug=news

Comment: Only 10 articles will be populate, for next 10, will have to add &page=2

Answer (score -3):

This example url worked for me... https://yourdomain.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts&categories=99

Comment: What does this post add to this question, that the other answers don't?

Comment: You don't need to add all that code above  - you can just access raw data via the location bar.

Comment: [This answer doesn't have any code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28540217/4875631), and pretty much sums up this post.